# Change where clause criteria based on column value

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

I am trying to figure out how to use a case statement in a where clause in order to select specific criteria based on the Product type column.  The first part of the where clause is common to both scenarios.  If the Product type is STD, I need to check to see if the EntryDate is between the firs day of the current month and yesterday.  If the Product is LTD, then I need to check to see if the EntryDate is between yesterday and seven days ago.

```
DECLARE @firstDayOfCurrentMonth datetime
SET @firstDayOfCurrentMonth = CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME)

SELECT DCMNumber, COUNT(*) AS PriorDenied
FROM  cauAssignedClaim 
WHERE RecordType = 'A' AND [Status] IS NULL AND
CASE WHEN Product = 'LTD' THEN EntryDate BETWEEN @firstDayOfCurrentMonth AND GETDATE()-1 
CASE WHEN Product = 'STD' THEN  EntryDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE()-1) AND GETDATE()-1 
END
GROUP BY [Status],  DCMNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN 
  CASE WHEN Product = 'LTD' THEN @FirstDatetc 
       ELSE DateAdd(blah)
  END 
AND GetDate()-1
```

That's assuming this is valid syntax since I've never tried it :)

I prefer this since it's quite concise - if you format it I suppose it's quite readable too

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a `CASE` statement here. You can just add additional clauses on your `WHERE`:

```
DECLARE @firstDayOfCurrentMonth datetime
SET @firstDayOfCurrentMonth = CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' +  CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME)

SELECT DCMNumber, COUNT(*) AS PriorDenied
FROM  cauAssignedClaim 
WHERE RecordType = 'A' 
    AND [Status] IS NULL 
    AND 
    ( 
        (
            Product = 'LTD' 
            AND EntryDate BETWEEN @firstDayOfCurrentMonth AND GETDATE()-1 
        )
        OR
        (
            Product = 'STD'
            AND EntryDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE()-1) AND GETDATE()-1 
        )
    )

GROUP BY [Status],  DCMNumber
```

Just as an FYI, here is a shorter way to get the first day of the month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0)
```